# NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

Route file

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/' , ['as' => '/', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getlogin']);
 Route::post('/Login', ['as'=> 'Login' , 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin' ]);
 Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'LoginController@getLogin'));

 Route::group(['middleware'=>['authen','roles' ]], function(){   
    Route::get('/logout' , ['as' => 'logout' , 'uses'=> 'LoginController@getLogout']);
    Route::get('/dashboard',['as'=> 'dashboard', 'uses'=> 'DashboardController@dashboard']);
});
```

loginController

```
    class LoginController extends Controller{
        use AuthenticatesUsers;
        protected $username = 'username';
        protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';
        protected $guard = 'web';

        public function getLogin()
        {`enter code here`
          if (Auth::guard('web')->check()){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
          }
            return view('login');
          }
         public function postLogin(Request $request)
        {
           $auth = Auth::guard('web')->attempt(['username'=>$request->username, 'password'=>$request->passwod , 'active' => 1]);

           if ($auth) {
             return redirect()->route('dashboard');
              }
            return redirect()-> route('/');
              }
         public function getLogout()
         {
            Auth::guard('web')->logout();
            return redirect()->route('/');
         }
    }
```

Whenever I try to login then the url goes to "http://localhost:8000/login&#10;" and NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 179: error happen.

I tried lots of time but I can't log into Laravel.

The Blade file

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">login</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }} ">
                       {{ csrf_field() }} 

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="username" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>






                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password"
                                    required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Clear route cache and try again: php artisan route:clear

Comment: no , Its not work :(

Comment: So when you visit /login you get redirected to login&#10 or when you submit login form at that time you are redirected there?

Comment: Also show blade template for login

Comment: how to post my .blade file i have ho idea , its too long , the blade file is i just attached above code please look my error

Comment: You can use pastebin.com if you don't know how to use SO's editor.

Comment: thanks you sir please look at my problem . , i don't know where is my mistake

Comment: You didn't ans this: So when you visit /login you get redirected to login&#10 or when you submit login form at that time you are redirected there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last **space** from the action attribute of the form:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }} ">
```

should be:

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
```

Also, make letter **L** small in login post route.

```
Route::post('/Login', ['as'=> 'Login' , 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin' ]);
```

Should be

```
Route::post('/login', ['as'=> 'Login' , 'uses' => 'LoginController@postLogin' ]);
```

Comment: no still not solved , still redirect to login form , when i give input for the form there is no happen . ..

Comment: Strange it should.
So when you visit /login you get redirected to login&#10 or when you submit login form at that time you are redirected there?

Comment: when i press submit button , i redirect the login page .. nothing happen

Comment: ok and that page(after submission) has URL http://localhost:8000/login&#10?

Comment: ok, Open login page in the web browser, inspect the form tag and show me the exact action attribute it has.

Comment: sir i don't know what i have done but now url become http://localhost:8000/login and problem become MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251: .. , now when i try to login that error happen , and stopping redirect the same page

Comment: Just make sure your form method is post

Comment: Run php artisan route:list command and show me the whole output

Answer (score 0):

try http://localhost:8000/yourProjetcName/login instead of localhost:8000/login&#10 if it does not work Try to access http://localhost:8000/yourProjetcName/index.php/login If it works, then you need to set up a virtual Host in your apache vHosts file

Answer (score 0):

I received this error when attempting to access an API route proxied by a middleware redirecting to another url when a certain condition was unmet. I don't know how redirect requests are handled in respect to APIs in Laravel, but I kept getting the error in the OP until I inspected the request object at the end of the stack trace.

I've googled for the specific behavior during API redirects but the only questions that keep popping up is something along the lines of "redirect to login". Nobody seems to have ever experienced what happens when an endpoint returns the response from a redirect.

So, since fixing the redirect in the middleware solved it for me, I'll assume this is the default behavior, and advise future visitors to this question to check the middlewares attached to their intended route.

In retrospect, throwing an error seems like a logical response (nevermind the NotFoundHttpException error not exactly being helpful in diagnosing what went wrong). The page you are being redirected to may require action such as requesting input, which client is in no position to fill. In such case, the response really is of no use.

Answer (score -1):

`ssh` to your server via putty (Windows) or terminal (Mac) and change ownership of the directory like so:

`chown -R daemon:daemon /your/script/directory`